# Check existence of file in archive (zip)

Tags: r

I'm using **unz** to extract data from a file within an archive. This actually works pretty well but unfortunately I've a lot of zip files and need to check the existence of a specific file within the archive. I could not manage to get a working solution with **if exists** or else.

Has anyone an idea how to perform a check if a file exists in an archive **without** extracting the whole archive before?

Example:

```
read.table(unz(D:/Data/Test.zip, "data.csv"), sep = ";")[-1,]
```

This works pretty well if `data.csv` exists but gives an error if the file is not available in the archive `Test.zip`.

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection  
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :  
  cannot locate file 'data.csv' in zip file 'D:/Data/Test.zip'
```

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: You can get a list of the files in the zip without unzipping it with `unzip(file.zip, list=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I'll check within my code and leave a message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `unzip(file, list = TRUE)$Name` to get the names of the files in the zip without having to unzip it.  Then you can check to see if the files you need are in the list.

```
## character vector of all file names in the zip
fileNames <- unzip("D:/Data/Test.zip", list = TRUE)$Name

## check if any of those are 'data.csv' (or others)
check <- basename(fileNames) %in% "data.csv"

## extract only the matching files
if(any(check)) {
    unzip("D:/Data/Test.zip", files = fileNames[check], junkpaths = TRUE)
}
```

You could probably put another `if()` statement to run `unz()` in cases where there is only one matched file name, since it's faster than running `unzip()` on a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the extension of the code from your previous comment. This works pretty well! I think I don't need another if() because the names in the zip files are unique. So I'm able to run unz()  directly on the archive if the file is available which seems to be pretty fast. Thanks again!